# How to get Rollback scripts for Spring-Batch 5.0 migration-oracle.sql

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

our project is going to upgrade to Spring-Boot 3.x, which uses Spring-Batch 5.x.

we use Oracle database, and we already have batch releated tables in production env, according to the [Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#oracle](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#oracle)
I can find the migration-oracle.sql scripts, but do we have rollback scripts for this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we only provide migration scripts from one version to the next one. We do not provide "rollback" scripts.

It is up to you to create the opposite SQL statements if you want to rollback.